# Gridview + Entity Framework + Big data

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

I am trying to figure out what the most efficient way to managed my Gridview that will potentially contain 30,000-500,000 records.  I am using entity framework code first if it matters.

It is hitting the database each time I change pages or click the edit commands.  I believe I am supposed to use custom paging to only retrieve certain rows at a time.  I think I have too much data for a session variable.

Do I need to switch to a custom paging method or does something sound wrong about my code to begin with?  I believe it is performing as it should be regarding rebinding each time.

Thanks Ahead

Comment: Why you added `Big Data` in your question?

Comment: I'm not sure how even the lowest bound number can be tractable. In other words, even if you could page through 30K results, how would that be useful? This is a question I consistently ask when questions like yours arise.

Comment: A user will never want to deal with such huge data. Show him/her a part of it and whenever he/she wants load more.

Comment: Sorry I thought this was considered Big data.

Also, I agree that it does not make sense to pull 30,000 records at once.  However, I am not sure how custom paging would work with entity framework.  Would I just pass through the id range that I want and edit the linq query?  Please forgive my ignorance, I am trying to learn.

Comment: @user1973080 `Where`, `Skip` and `Take` will be your friends here for paging. For such a simple case, SQL generated by EF should be more than decent.

Answer (score 1):

When you work with a large database, entity framework is slowing things down alot, that's why on my over 2 million records database i use [DAPPER](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/). It is very easy to use and you can read the documentation in 5 minutes. No need to say that Dapper will give me the data back in a matter of seconds vs minutes (up to one hr) for EntityFramework.

When you will use DAPPER you will have to create a custom paging...

Comment: That is pretty interesting.  I am going to research into this more.  Thank you for your feedback.